# How do I get the Image information with using UrlFetchApp()?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to use UrlFetchApp to request and hope to get response.

```
var url = "https://i.imgur.com/dCv0PzY.gif";
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{
      'headers': {'Content-Type': 'image/png'}});
Logger.log(res);
```

But response is too much data.

Like the picture below.

[image]

[I read other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622173/need-sheets-script-to-save-img-to-drive)

There is a method getBlob(),but I only get the string "Blob" after use it.

[And the second discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257264/how-to-get-the-size-in-pixels-of-a-jpeg-image-i-get-with-urlfetchapp-fetchpho)

It uses content attribute,but I get syntax error,too.(the method not exist).

.

.

Is  this a Base64 data or other type data?

And how can I get the image information(width,height,etc)

on the recommanded way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can  access Drive API through Advanced Google services to retrieve some metadata:

#### Sample script:

```
function getImageMeta(){
var url = "[IMAGE_LINK]";
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{
      'headers': {'Content-Type': 'image/png'}});
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(res.getContent()).setName('test'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100)));
  var meta = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).imageMediaMetadata;
  Logger.log(meta)
  file.setTrashed(true);
}
```

#### References:

- [Files § get § imageMediaMetadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files#resource)